# Firebase Database Error at Uploading

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am having some issues at putting files into the Firebase Database. I am getting error at this line: `String download_url = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();`, mentioning "error: cannot find symbol method getDownloadUrl()".

Here is the code:
https://pastebin.com/ESXBiZ9a

And my Firebase dependecies are:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
```

Could anyone point where I have to change, maybe the method, in order to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should like this -

```
filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>()
{
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot)
      {
          String download_url = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl().toString();
      }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
   {
        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) 
        {
        }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Now the getDownloadUrl() method is changed and we are now supposed to use getDownloadUrl with the storage reference.See this https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference#getDownloadUrl()

```
 final StorageReference filepath = mImageStorage.child("message_images").child(push_id + ".jpg");
     UploadTask uploadTask = filepath.putFile(imageUri);

     Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
         @Override
         public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
        if(!task.isSuccessful()){
            throw task.getException();
        }
             return filepath.getDownloadUrl();
         }
     }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
         @Override
         public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
             Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
             String download_url = downloadUri.toString();
           .
           .
           .
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it change to:

```
task.getResult().getStorage().getDownloadUrl().toString();
```